# Ruins Game - Puzzle Edition

Tags: information-theory

The ruins are clear to you. They're real, and you're trapped by lava. But before you can get the button, there's a puzzle:

Send:

> word

Receive:

> ord

Send:

> big bruh

Receive:

> ig uh

Send:

> ending stuff

Receive:

> ing uff

Find my hH5kwC5D3lfqaqlzaMVFkxFNuqCQHrrcxuC37ccRE1Q= given this text:

> 3qYEsCzMseHI/39IWlnnnzP1vxkRmo7lpIJnyJnfBtyhAug0XfSfFfwu+u6p7BmfMzJjJO2ZFoEU3Nd3dhw6Nng=

Okay fine, have this information:

stream
enigma
base64
[Hyperlink](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/)
key: word

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer - starting at the end:

> Using the hyperlink, we end up at an encryption tool - which itself has a link to a decryption tool. Decrypting `3qYEsCzMseHI/39IWlnnnzP1vxkRmo7lpIJnyJnfBtyhAug0XfSfFfwu+u6p7BmfMzJjJO2ZFoEU3Nd3dhw6Nng=` using the Enigma algorithm in STREAM mode, using "word" as the key

We reveal...

> another link to another encrypt/decrypt tool

Which we can then use to...

> Decrypt `hH5kwC5D3lfqaqlzaMVFkxFNuqCQHrrcxuC37ccRE1Q=` into "regex"

So the aim of this is to:

> Determine the regular expression that will transform the "send" input into the "receive" output

Comment: Well, if anything that works with the 3 input we're given is acceptable: `([aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*\b).+?\b)` . Starts from last vowel of a word, matches the rest of it

Comment: +1 Good start! You got it!

Comment: @LukasRotter It finds all the *pieces*, but you have to join them.

Comment: hint: find the regex such that the rot13("".wbva(er.svaqnyy(ertrk, grkg))) gives us the necessary output.